# How to detect idle state on the browser which use webkit in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found a solution worked around with detecting idle state of user on browser on [Detecting if the user is idle with JavaScript and YUI 3](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/02/detecting-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript-and-yui-3/).

It worked fine on FireFox, but sometimes it did not do not in Chrome, Safari. The mousemove event was called all of time with those browser.

Any one has other solution for it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for it now. In the idle-timer.js, I updated it as follow
1/ Search the follow code

```
var idle    = false,        //indicates if the user is idle
        tId     = -1,           //timeout ID
        enabled = false,        //indicates if the idle timer is enabled
        timeout = 30000;        //the amount of time (ms) before the user is considered idle
```

and add two below lines at next of above

```
prevMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
        currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
```

If your code did not work, you can try with event.screenX, event.screenY.

2/ Replace this line

```
clearTimeout(tId);
```

with

```
if(e.type == 'mousemove'){
            currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
            currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
            if(currentMousePos == prevMousePos){
                enabled = false;
            }
            else{
                prevMousePos = currentMousePos;
                clearTimeout(tId);
            }
        }
        else if(e.type == 'mousemove'){
            clearTimeout(tId);
        }

    else if(e.type == 'keydown'){
        clearTimeout(tId);
    }
```